# Echo all variable from while loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I hava a while loop that throught to databases records. Like this:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($articles = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     // something happen here
}
```

How can I echo each $articles out of the while loop ? So I don't want to have something like

```
while(...){
    echo $articles['article_name'];
}
```

How can I save all the $articles['article_name'] into an array an echo them back ?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$articleList = array();

while(...){
    $articleList[] = $articles['article_name'];
}
```

That will put everything in the array `$articleList` for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

```
$articles = array();
while ($art = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $articles[] = $art;
}
print_r($articles);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$i=0; $articles = array();
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");
while($articles[] = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     echo $articles['article_name'][$i];
     $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table");

while($articles = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
     $names[] = $articles['article_name'];

}
echo 'array of names are :';
 print_r($names);
```